# Unable to Read hashmap using JSTL on JSP page

Tags: jsp, hashmap, jstl

I have the following code on my JSP page:

```jsp
<c:when test="${empty requestScope.isUpcomingMovieFlag}">
<c:forEach var="screening" items="${movie.extendedTheatreList}" begin="0" end = "5">
<c:set var="url" value="${screening.theatreBean.listingBean.url}"></c:set>
<c:set var="key" value="${screening.theatreBean.id}"/>
Test: ${key}
<c:set var="showDetails" value="${movie.movieShowTimings[key]}"/>
```

When i manually enter a key in the line

```jsp
<c:set var="showDetails" value="${movie.movieShowTimings[key]}"/>
```

Example

```jsp
<c:set var="showDetails" value="${movie.movieShowTimings['2410']}"/>
```

I get the desired result but when I use a JSTL variable eg.`key` which i have set I do not get any entry from my map. Please advise.

My variable key is not empty which i have verified by printing on screen.

Answer (score 0):

Advise you to rename the key variable to some other name to not clash with the `key` property of the map.

```
<c:set var="keyInfo" value="${screening.theatreBean.id}"/>
<c:set var="showDetails" value="${movie.movieShowTimings[keyInfo]}"/>
```